# Converting strings separated by commas to arrays and merging arrays that are contained within one variable

Tags: php, arrays

The following code is used to get some primary keys from various database entries and merging the unique values into a single array for downstream applications.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id;";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  $results = '';

  while ($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results .= $input['micro_analysis'];
  }

  $rows = explode(',', $results);
  $final_rows = array_unique(array_merge($rows));
```

The problem I have is that each row from the database has a string, for example `1,4` and `2,3`. When the strings are merged they become `1,42,3` which is a problem, because this code then produces a array like this:
`Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 42 [2] => 3 )` instead of this: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 )`.

Anybody have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append to the end of your `$result` variable you can add a comma to it. Giving you:

```
"1,4,2,3,"
```

as your `$results` string once your `while` loop is complete. You can then remove the trailing comma using `substr()`:

```
substr($results, 0, -1);
```

Combing all of these ideas your code should look like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$results = '';

while ($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $results .= $input['micro_analysis'] . ',';
}

$results = substr($results, 0, -1);
$rows = explode(',', $results);
$final_rows = array_unique(array_merge($rows));
```

Comment: Actually there is the possibility that `$input['micro_analysis']` contains an empty string and you would end up with something like `$results='1,2,,,,3,4,5,'`, so you would have to remove more than one comma. This could be solved by `$rows = array_filter(explode(',', $results));` (and remove the "`substr($results, 0, -1)`" line).

Comment: @Freddy Yes, this is a good solution to fix multiple empty values. However, I think, in terms of being more efficient, it would be better if you simply added an `if` statement before the `$results .=` to check if it is not an empty string, and if this is the case only then append it. This way you wouldn't need to loop over the array

Comment: @Nick Parsons Yes, I agree!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by generate a fresh array .
 Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$results = array();

while ($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $results[] = $input['micro_analysis'];
}
$final_rows = array_unique($results);
```

Comment: Getting the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: As this is generating an array you have to see the result by using print_r or implode this array as a string